# How to determine user input is digits in string

Tags: c++

If I have s1255678a and I use 
(Isalpha[0]!=0 && isalpha[8]!=0)
Return 1// to determine array 0and array 8 is alphabet 
How do I use similar code to determine from array 1 to array 7 is digits

Comment: One solution is to use a regex expression that starts with one letter, matches to the digit character 7 times, and then ends with another letter. Another solution is to parse the string character by character and use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` from the C standard library. The answer will also depend on the encoding if you happen to use UTF-16 or UTF-32 or other formats besides something like ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a regular expression.
This should point you in the right direction.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

I think something like this should do it.

```
string input("s1255678a");
regex pattern("[A-Za-z][0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]")
regex_match(input,pattern)
```

Comment: This tutorial has code snippets https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/12/cpp-11-regex-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to iterate over the whole string and check if it is a digit:

```
for(int i = 0; str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
   if(isdigit[i]!=0)
       //doSomething
}
```

Here, str[i]!='\0' checks if the string has finished or not. If instead, you simply want to do this check for array indexes from 1 to 7, you can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=7 ;i++)
{
   if(isdigit[i]!=0)
       //doSomething
}
```

Comment: isdigit() is a method. you using it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isdigit() to check if the char in string is a digit.Below program is an example-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
   char str[]="This is you number right 123456789";
   int i=0,len = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
   while(i<len){
   if (isdigit(str[i]))
   {
      printf ("%c\n",str[i]);
   }
   i++;
}
return 0;

}
```